# Derivation of zero temperature conductivity in Dirac materials - Einstein formula

Tags: condensed-matter, graphene

I've come across this in multiple papers but have no idea where this comes from. For the Dirac materials the zero temperature conductivity $\sigma$ can then be expressed as

$\sigma = e^2v_{F}^2D\ \tau/3$,

where $e$ is the electronic charge, $v_{F}$ is the Fermi velocity, $D$ is the density of states and $\tau$ is the relaxation time. Any pointers on how to derive this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps Sec. III A of http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4731 will help. They describe how to derive this in graphene within Boltzmann transport theory.